# Read string word by word with .Substring?

Tags: c#, wpf, string, substring

I'v got the following String `string gen = "Action;Adventure;Drama;Horror;`
I tried to seperate the string word by word with .substring like: `gen.Substring(gen.IndexOf(';')+1, gen.IndexOf(';'))`
But my output is just "Advent".

Any help?

Background: The string collects the names of checkboxes that are checked. The string is then saved in a database. 
I want to read out the string an check each checkbox on another form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split it like this:

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      String value = "Action;Adventure;Drama;Horror";
      Char delimiter = ';';
      String[] substrings = value.Split(delimiter);
      foreach (var substring in substrings)
         Console.WriteLine(substring);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Just split it:

```
var parts = gen.Split(';');
```

(Then you can iterate over that via `foreach`.)

Comment: That was fast...and easy ;-) Thanks